# Многопоточность в C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Кто в курсе многопоточности в C++? Решил поизучать многопоточность в C++ и заступорился. Начал читать книгу Энтони Уильямса "Параллельное программирование на C++ в действии", но там рассказывается о классе thread. Позже нашел такую штуку OpenMP. Может кто объяснит что есть что и с чего начать?

Comment: дочитайте Уильямся. класс thread для с++ 11 и старше - нормальное решение для начала. OpenMP это немножко дальше и другое.

Comment: Вот то, что в книге, то и есть многопоточное программирование на C++11. Там, кстати, скоро должно 2-ое издание подойти, с учетом C++17.

Answer (score 3):

Многопоточность это свойство не языка а операционки. Например, язык С++ вполне существовал для однопоточной MS DOS (мир праху ее). Есть, конечно, библиотеки С++ для организации потоков. Но это не более, чем надстройки над вызовами API соответствующей ОС. Так что можно читать не учебник по С++, а справочник по API Вашей ОС. Недавно с удивлением узнал, что популярная в некоторых кругах библиотека C++ pthread не имеет параметра "приоритет потока" при создании потока. Тогда как в API ОС Windows или Linux параметр "приоритет потока" присутствует. Так что полное управление потоком, скорее всего, возможно только вызовами API Вашей ОС. Ну, или кто-то порадеет и напишет библиотеку потоков, которая не будет ограничивать возможности API ОС.